# Difference between "while" loop and "do while" loop

Tags: c, loops

What is the difference between while loop and do while loop. I used to think both are completely same.Then I came across following piece of code:

```
do {
        printf("Word length... ");
        scanf("%d", &wdlen);
    } while(wdlen<2);
```

This code works perfectly. It prints word length and tascans the input. But when I changed it to

```
while(wdlen<2){
        printf("Word length... ");
        scanf("%d", &wdlen);
    }
```

It gives a blank screen. It do not work. So there is some functional difference between both loops. Can anybody explain it?

Is there any other difference in these two?

Comment: while loop checks the condition initially and then executes.. but do-while executes the body atleast once even if the condition is false..

Comment: Both are equally broken because neither of them check the return value of `scanf()`.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The **do while** loop executes the content of the loop once before checking the condition of the while.

Whereas a **while** loop will check the condition first before executing the content.

In this case you are waiting for user input with scanf(), which will never execute in the **while** loop as wdlen is not initialized and may just contain a garbage value which may be greater than 2.

Comment: "wdlen (assumedly starts at 0) and will never be < 2" - back in my math class I was taught that 0 < 2 ;-)

Comment: 0 < 2 == false? Are you sure?

Comment: Thanks buddy. I understood. Any other difference in these two?

Comment: If I were a compiler and wdlen would not be initialized, I'd skip the whole block because if it's undefined it might as well be always > 2.

Answer (score 21):

**While** : your condition is at the begin of the loop block, and makes possible *to never enter the loop*.

**Do While** : your condition is at the end of the loop block, and makes obligatory *to enter the loop at least one time*.

Comment: tnx for good replay.There is only one difference??is there other difference??

Comment: @AminM The latter requires two extra characters to type.

Comment: While is sometimes used almost like an if because when the condition isn't true the loop never gets entered, and inside the loop is code to deal with the condition being true until it isn't anymore.

Comment: There are other programming languages, where `while ... do` is also written as `while ... do` but `do ... while` is written as `repeat ... until`. This is more in line with common English language.

Answer (score 3):

```
do {
    printf("Word length... ");
    scanf("%d", &wdlen);
} while(wdlen<2);
```

A `do-while` loop guarantees the execution of the loop at least once because it checks the loop condition AFTER the loop iteration. Therefore it'll print the string and call scanf, thus updating the wdlen variable.

```
while(wdlen<2){
    printf("Word length... ");
    scanf("%d", &wdlen);
}
```

As for the `while` loop, it evaluates the loop condition BEFORE the loop body is executed. `wdlen` probably starts off as more than 2 in your code that's why you never reach the loop body.

Comment: "probably starts off less than 2"... `while(wdlen<2)`... oops?

Answer (score 3):

do while in an exit control loop.
while is an entry control loop.

Answer (score 3):

**While:**

1. entry control loop
2. condition is checked before loop execution
3. never execute loop if condition is false
4. there is no semicolon at the end of while statement

**Do-while:**

1. exit control loop
2. condition is checked at the end of loop
3. executes false condition at least once since condition is checked later
4. there is semicolon at the end of while statement.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in when the condition gets evaluated. In a `do..while` loop, the condition is not evaluated until the end of each loop. That means that a `do..while` loop will **always** run at least once. In a `while` loop, the condition is evaluated at the start.

Here I assume that `wdlen` is evaluating to false (i.e., it's bigger than 1) at the beginning of the `while` loop, so the while loop never runs. In the `do..while` loop, it isn't checked until the end of the first loop, so you get the result you expect.

Answer (score 1):

**Do while** loop will be executed atleast once.......but **while** loop will check the condition first and then it may or may not get executed depending on the condition.

In your example wdlen may assume any garbage value which is > 2 so **while** loop will never get executed.

whereas **do while** loop will be ececuted and will tell u to enter the value and check that value in terminating condition

Answer (score 1):

```
while(wdlen<2){
  ...
 }
```

If wdlen (assuming it's a stack variable) is not initialized or assigned a value before the while loop is entered, it will contain whatever was in that space in memory before (i.e. garbage). So if the garbage value is < 2, the loop executes, otherwise it doesn't.

```
do{
 ...
}while(wdlen<2)
```

will execute once and then checks on condition to run loop again, and this time it might succeed if by chance wdlen which is uninitialized is found to be less than 2.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `wdlen` starts with a value >=2, so in the second case the loop condition is initially false and the loop is never entered.

In the second case the loop body is executed before the `wdlen<2` condition is checked for the first time, so the `printf`/`scanf` is executed at least once.

Comment: Larger than 2, I assume you mean?

Comment: @Stephen: yes, changed that :)

Comment: Heh, well caught. Your change actually made me catch an error in my answer (I had said "it must be greater than 2"!), so cheers ;).

Answer (score 0):

**while** test the **condition** before executing **statements** within the **while** loop.

**do while** test the **condition** after having executed **statement** within the loop.

source: let us C

Comment: This question is 3 years old, and has already an answer... +1 for being a hero.

Answer (score 0):

while test the condition **before** executing statements in the while loop.

do while test the condition **after** having executed statement inside the loop.

Comment: You're not wrong, but it's maybe a bit late to be answering this?

Comment: may be it's late but I wanted to answer his question with a simple / short response

Answer (score 0):

In WHILE first check the condition and then execute the program
In DO-WHILE loop first execute the program at least one time then check the condition

Comment: 6 years too late. There were already 12 answers to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between do while (exit check) and while (entry check) is that while entering in do while it will not check but in while it will first check

The example is as such:

**Program 1:**

```
int a=10;
do{
System.out.println(a);
}
while(a<10);

//here the a is not less than 10 then also it will execute once as it will execute do while exiting it checks that a is not less than 10 so it will exit the loop
```

**Program 2:**

```
int b=0;
while(b<10)
{
System.out.println(b);
}
//here nothing will be printed as the value of b is not less than 10 and it will not let enter the loop and will exit
```

**output Program 1:**

10

**output Program 2:**

[nothing is printed]

***note:***

output of the program 1 and program 2 will be same if we assign a=0 and b=0 and also put a++; and b++; in the respective body of the program.

Answer (score 0):

**While Loop:**

```
while(test-condition)
{
      statements;
      increment/decrement;
}
```

1. Lower Execution Time and Speed
2. Entry Conditioned Loop
3. No fixed number of iterations

**Do While Loop:**

```
do
{
      statements;
      increment/decrement;
}while(test-condition);
```

1. Higher Execution Time and Speed
2. Exit Conditioned Loop
3. Minimum one number of iteration

Find out more on this topic here: **[Difference Between While and Do While Loop](http://www.codingalpha.com/difference-between-while-and-do-while-loop-in-c/)**

This is valid for C programming, Java programming and other languages as well because the concepts remain the same, only the syntax changes.

Also, another small but a differentiating factor to note is that the do while loop consists of a **semicolon** at the end of the while condition.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a `while` constructs from Step 1 versus a `do while` is that any expressions within the `do {}` will be running at least once regardless of the condition within the `while()` clause.

```
println("\nStep 2: How to use do while loop in Scala")
var numberOfDonutsBaked = 0
do {
  numberOfDonutsBaked += 1
  println(s"Number of donuts baked = $numberOfDonutsBaked")
} while (numberOfDonutsBaked < 5)
```

Here is detail explaination: [Explanation](https://coderforevers.com/c-2/c-tutorial-c-2/while-do-while-loop/)
Visit: [coderforevers](https://coderforevers.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The most important difference between `while` and `do-while` loop is that in `do-while`, the block of code is executed at least once, even though the condition given is false.

To put it in a different way :

- While- your condition is at the begin of the loop block, and makes possible to never enter the loop.
- In While loop, the condition is first tested and then the block of code is executed if the test result is true.