# Difference between Pre-Tested and Post-Tested Loops

Tags: vb.net-2010

I've just transferred into a computer class at my high school, we're learning VB 2010. I've been studying hard, but this question has me stumped:

"Two procedures with parameters are shown below. One uses a pre-tested loop and the other uses a post-tested loop. After making the procedure call,

```
pattern (-2,"####")
```

The output from each procedure is different.

PRE TESTED

```
pattern (start as integer, hash as string)
    DIM counter as integer
     Counter = 0
     DO WHILE counter < start
         lbldisplay.text = hash
         Counter = counter + 1
     LOOP
     END SUB
```

POST TESTED

```
pattern(start as integer, hash as string)
    DIM counter as integer
    Counter=0
      DO
    lbldisplay.text = hash
    Counter = counter + 1
      LOOP WHILE counter > start
      END SUB
```

What would happen in each procedure? What would the result be? I've got my head around some of the basics but this has really stumped me. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between "while" loop and "do while" loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625759/difference-between-while-loop-and-do-while-loop)

Answer (score 0):

In Short: a "POST-TESTED" loop will always execute at least once.  Where as a "PRE-TESTED" loop may not execute at all.